# Swift editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to add some edit actions in my tableview.  However, I cannot figure out what to put in for UITableViewRowAction!.  It is represented in the code as *IDK*.

```
func Done(UITableViewRowAction!,
    NSIndexPath!) -> Void {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let complete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Done", handler: Done(_IDK_, indexPath))

    let arrayofactions: Array = [complete]

    return arrayofactions
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        println("delete")
    }
    let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Done") { action, index in
        println("done")
    }
    return [delete, done]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A closure worked for me in this instance.

```
func Done(UITableViewRowAction!,
NSIndexPath!) -> Void {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:      NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

let complete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Done", handler: { (action, indexPath.row) -> Void in 
 'handle your action here'

})

let arrayofactions: Array = [complete]

return arrayofactions
}
```

I found a blog post about this and it worked for me.

Comment: here is a link to that blog [link](http://http://timbroder.com/2014/08/uitableviewcell-action-swiping-in-ios8-and-swift.html)

Comment: In addition, you can use the Swift trailing closure syntax for cleaner code: let complete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath.row) -> Void in 
 'handle your action here'

}

Comment: The above code only compiles for me when I remove the ".row", like so:
UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in 'handle your action here' }

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 2.2**

I had to update this way

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool 
{
   return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? 
{
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") 
    { action, index in
        print("delete")
    }
    let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Done") 
    { action, index in
        print("done")
    }
    return [delete, done]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
// All tasks are handled by blocks defined in editActionsForRowAtIndexPath, however iOS8 requires this method to enable editing
}
```